# How to fake the focus on a Material-ui TextField from a button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My web app has a method of filling in a text field indirectly, and as it's multiple clicks (for context, it's a calendar) and multiple fields, I would like to show the use which field they're filling in when they click the next button.

*I cannot put focus in the textfield itself*. That would take the user away from the interface they're clicking on.

I have this working for input, but I cannot get this working for textfields. Here is the two sets of code specifically, where am I going wrong?

### TextField (not working)

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  }
}));

export default function Inputs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const focusedRef = useRef();
  const toggleFocusOnElement = () => {
    setFocused(prevFocused => !prevFocused);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (focused) {
      focusedRef.current.classList.add("Mui-focused");
    } else {
      focusedRef.current.classList.remove("Mui-focused");
    }
  }, [focused]);
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={toggleFocusOnElement}>
        {focused ? "Remove" : "Fake"} focus
      </Button>
      <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <TextField
          inputRef={focusedRef}
          defaultValue="Hello world"
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "description" }}
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

### Input (working)

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button, Input } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  }
}));

export default function Inputs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const focusedRef = useRef();
  const toggleFocusOnElement = () => {
    setFocused(prevFocused => !prevFocused);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (focused) {
      focusedRef.current.classList.add("Mui-focused");
    } else {
      focusedRef.current.classList.remove("Mui-focused");
    }
  }, [focused]);
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={toggleFocusOnElement}>
        {focused ? "Remove" : "Fake"} focus
      </Button>
      <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <Input
          ref={focusedRef}
          defaultValue="Hello world"
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "description" }}
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Is there a way around this limitation or a better way to fake the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mui-focused` class needs to be applied to a `<div>` that [contains the `<input>` element](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.4/packages/material-ui/src/InputBase/InputBase.js#L409). The `inputRef` prop puts a ref on the `<input>` element itself, whereas the `ref` on `Input` (whether directly or via TextField InputProps) is [placed on the containing div](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.4/packages/material-ui/src/InputBase/InputBase.js#L419).

I would recommend that you don't use refs or `useEffect` at all for this purpose and just apply the class name more directly:

```
        <TextField
          InputProps={{ className: focused ? "Mui-focused" : undefined }}
          defaultValue="Hello world"
        />
```

[image: Edit Fake TextField focus]

Comment: My use of `useEffect` is jsut to show this off in the question.Would setting the classname not override the class applied?

Comment: But it is tied in to manipulating the className via the ref, but if you're managing `focused` as state, there's no reason to use a ref at all -- you can just manipulate the className prop via React.

Comment: Using refs could make sense if you aren't actually managing a `focused` state and instead doing all of this imperatively in event handlers.

Comment: I'm not actually managing focused in state IRL. But this is a great answer regardless.

Answer (score 0):

## `InputRef={focusedRef}` and `InputProps={{'ref':focusedRef}}` are not the same.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button, TextField, Input } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  }
}));

export default function Inputs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const focusedRef = useRef();
  const toggleFocusOnElement = () => {
    setFocused(prevFocused => !prevFocused);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (focused) {
      focusedRef.current.classList.add("Mui-focused");
    } else {
      focusedRef.current.classList.remove("Mui-focused");
    }
  }, [focused]);
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={toggleFocusOnElement}>
        {focused ? "Remove" : "Fake"} focus
      </Button>
      <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <TextField
          InputProps={{ ref: focusedRef }}
          defaultValue="Hello world"
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

I'm uncertain why this would be, but I can confirm the above code works for me in a codesandbox.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should just simply call `focus()` and `blur()` method of the HTML control.
This will automatically give/remove focus to/from the element and achieve what you want to achieve.

```js
const toggleFocusOnElement = () => {
    setFocused(prevFocused => !prevFocused);
    if (focused) {
      focusedRef.current.blur();
    } else {
      focusedRef.current.focus();
    }
};
```

Comment: Ahhhh, but I want to fake the focus, not actually put the cursor into the text field, so this does not work. I'll go make that clearer.